# TYPO3 - TCA - Input (inputLink) Output Title?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

how can i output from the TCA - Input (inputLink) Link the Title?

My TYPO3 BE "Input":

```
t3://page?uid=5 - - Test
```

or

```
t3://page?uid=5 - - "Test Test"
```

Now i need only the Title in my TYPO3 Fluid Template.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution yet in the core to get only the title from a typolink string. You need a new ViewHelper for it.

You can parse out the title with using the Core functionality. Look out for the `LinkBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks, jep we build a new VH !